# Better Debugging for Sharepoint 2013 and Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sharepoint-server, debugging

I am new to Sharepoint. I have used asp.net mvc the last 5 years and Web Forms the 7 years prior. ANY HELP is greatly appreciated in helping me get up to speed with Sharepoint development.

I just started a new job where they have spent a month and a half creating a proof of concept in Sharepoint. Most of the code so far is client side javascript sitting inside some sharepoint-hosted aspx pages, with limited use of sharepoint functionality. So far, we have some files programmatically saving to a share point list. We also have a web api project in the project calling a database.

What I’m immediately noticing is a much worse developer debugging experience with Visual Studio and Sharepoint. Here are some issues:

1) I have to install SharePoint and Visual Studio on Windows Server 2012 on Oracle Virtual Box (or other VM host). I have to run Visual Studio on this VM to debug. This isn’t the end of the world, but would be nicer to debug on my local Windows 2010 machine from Visual Studio.

2) This part is very painful. Every time I debug Sharepoint, it’s deployed to IIS. Even if I change some client side code, I need to deploy and hit ctrl F5 on the Web page to see the change. Very time consuming to debug this way!

3) Edit and continue doesn’t work on server side code.

4) Client side debugging in Visual Studio doesnt work. Can’t hit breakpoints or “debugger” statements in javascript code.

5) I can’t set a breakpoint and hit it in the web api project. The web api project is published and hosted as a separate web site with different port in IIS on the same box. It has to be published separately to IIS if changes are made to it in Visual Studio.

6) I want to do sharepoint-specific tasks like save to sharepoint lists initiated from javascript in addition to grabbing data from the back-end database via a separate web api web site. This means I call web api, but since it’s a separate web site from sharepoint, integration and security with sharepoint is lost. The logged in user within sharepoint is not available within the web api site.

7)I tried refencing an additional class library project that the main sharepoint project references. Do I need to deploy this project dll to the GAC? Sharepoint project throws a runtime error screen when accessing this dll. How can I make this dll deploy properly and easily when debugging? Do I need to sign this dll and get sharepoint to trust it somehow?

8) Is there a way to make the starting page of the sharepoint application an asp.net mvc page or other web api-compatible web page, rathere than a web forms aspx page? Of course, improved Visual Studio debugging similar to traditional asp.net mvc solution development is desired.
——

I know I’ve asked a lot of questions, but I’ve done a lot of research and still haven’t found a clear path to victory.

Thanks for your help!